# How can i make a Spring bean which can be configured in setters as well constructor dependency?

Tags: java, spring

This is a question that was asked in an interview .
The question was that a bean has certain properties which we configure in .xml file and then we inject it but let's say that one does not know that the properties or the properties will be different for different Beans . So how will we make that bean so that we are able to configure it in runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I think externalizing the bean values, something like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

then following the example having your `jdbc.properties` file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://production:9002
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=root
```

the properties can be configured at runtime